# How does a private network take advantage of new EIPs

Tags: go-ethereum, eip

Say, I setup a private network using `geth`. My genesis config is made aware of ByzantiumBlock and all nodes (tx & miners) are all happy and healthy.

Now `Constantinople` release is on the horizon. How could my running network take advantage of new features available in `Constantinople`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you should update your genesis.json file by specifying a block number to fork from.

- Geth example (mainnet genesis file): https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/18268/files
- Parity example (POA Sokol genesis file): https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/pull/10155/files

Also, make sure you're using one of the latest versions of your client which supports Constantinople features.